# RxSwift How to use combineLatest?

Tags: ios, swift, reactive-programming, observable

I have defined:

```
let currentHours:Variable<Float> = Variable(0.0)
let currentRate:Variable<Float>  = Variable(0.0)
```

and I would like to make an Observable with combineLatest to sum these two value:

```
Observable.combineLatest(currentHours, currentRate, { (h, r) -> Float in
    return Float(h+r)
})
```

and I also try:

```
let c =  Observable.combineLatest(currentHours, currentRate) { $0 + $1 }
```

I always get compiler error.
thanks

Comment: Dont forget to accept the answer if it has solve your problem

Answer (score 53):

Try this:

```
let currentHours:Variable<Float> = Variable(0.0)
let currentRate:Variable<Float>  = Variable(0.0)

let hoursAndRate = Observable.combineLatest(currentHours.asObservable(), currentRate.asObservable()){
        return $0 + $1
}
```

As you can see the key is in passing currentHours and currentRate **as Observables** in the function parameters.